# using Vuetify, when i try to print a page it only shows the first one

Tags: printing, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have an app built using [Vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com/).

One of the pages is used for orders and I want the user to be able to print it.

The problem is that if I have scroll in the page, only the first page shows with a scrollbar:

[image]

How can I make it display all other pages for print?

**UPDATE**

I have a `.scroll-y` class on the main section, if I use this css for print:

```
 @media print{
      body,
      html {
        height: 5000px !important;
      }

      .scroll-y {
        height: 100% !important;
      }
    }
```

it works, but obviously i don't want a set height of 5000px for every print,
I can use js to calculate the height and set it but I'm wondering if there is a better/easier way?

Comment: Are you using a `v-data-table`? I am assuming the scrollbar is just a reflection of the available data (like pagination?). If not, you have to adapt your css when printing to not scroll e.g. use `@media screen` and `@media print` rules.

Comment: I'm using `v-data-table` but with no pagination, and i'm also using a `@media print` css, see my update

Comment: Why do you need the `height` on the body? Using absolute positioning?

Comment: because i use vuetify which gives the body a height of 100vh, which apparently does not work for printing.

Comment: Instead of using `5000px` couldn't just set it to `100%` or `auto` (with important?).Also I noticed this issue which might be relevant for you if you are using FF? https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/2757

Comment: I'm using chrome, and setting it to 100% did not work

Comment: I would try to set overflow:visible - You do not need any scroll in that print preview. Also You could try to set 100vh for the height, but I am not sure it would do the trick.

Comment: tried 100vh, didn't work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to change CSS, adding something like this:

```
@media print {
  body { 
    overflow: auto;
    height: auto; 
  }
  .scroll-y {
     height: auto;
     overflow: visible;
  }
}
```

So `.scroll-y` occupied all space needed, and body will grow up to right printed size.
Of course you must adds html elements for printing page break, preview print of your view on typical print size (i.e. A4) and adding where need an breakup print element as

```
 <div class="print-break-page"></div>
```

with css:

```
 .print-break-page {
       page-break-after: always;
 }
```

Comment: How do i know where to add `<div class="print-break-page"></div>` the content is dynamic?

Comment: I make print preview of web page, and based on what I see, I choose where put this div to break content. For instance, if you have a list of elements and into preview you see 21th element cross between page and next one, then before 21th element, put this div.

Comment: even if i could do this, which is hard since the data is dynamic, I'm still dependent on the screen size, since on smaller screens i'll see less elements

Comment: Hard to say exactly without analyzing HTML page structures, but another criterion is to add this CSS property `page-break-after: auto` for every section of elements.

Comment: IMHO, I don't know if you can avoid analyzing content and determining whether it can fit on a given printed page. In our use case, we're showing fixed-size grid elements and can easily see only e.g. 16 items fit on one page, so we handle overflow beyond 16 items begins a new page.

Answer (score 3):

You have to change the overflow and the height of the main section (the body on my example):

```
@media print {
  body { 
    overflow: auto;
    height: auto; 
  }
}
```

Link to the demo on codepen:
https://codepen.io/andersanmiguel/pen/NXyxPE?editors=0100 (you can export it form there)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Ander and @g.annunziata for pointing me in the right direction, the final setup that worked for me was:

```
 body,
  .scroll-y {
    overflow: visible !important;
    height: auto !important;
  }
```