# Are there a way to print the v-sheet/v-card and all of childs component on a4?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

As the title, I wanted to do the documentation pdf on the form component that the user have input that is childs of v-card.

Or are there ways to make a document out of vuetify?? Can I have your solution and opinion on the docment making??

(Vuetify 2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiet way would be with https://github.com/joseluisq/printd. It will be made A4 automatically by the browser in printing dialog.

```vue
<template>
  <v-btn @click="print">Print</v-btn>
  <v-card ref="card">
    ...
  </v-card>
</template>

<script setup>
  import { ref } from 'vue';
  import { Printd } from 'printd';

  const card = ref(null);
  const print = () => {
    const d = new Printd();
    d.print(card.value);
  }
</script>
```

(I didn't actually run the code)

You might need to fix card's scroll for printing e.g. like here https://stackoverflow.com/a/48164080/1216939, so the browser correctly breaks it into multiple pages. Or adjust css, e.g. remove tompost margins/paddings. See `.print` second argument, or I would prefer making adjustments in media block:

```vue
<style scoped>
@media print {
  v-card {
    overflow: auto;
    height: auto; 
  }
}
</style>
```